# Reactjs setState not working

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm running into an issue where my console is telling me setState is not defind. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I preload the my object (data) in the constructor. I then pass it through to a table where it is displayed. When a user then selects an option from a dropdown it should only show the filtered data. I've bound the function in the constructor so I'm not sure what I've done wrong. Code is below:

```
import React, {Component} from ‘react’;
import moment from ‘moment’;
import {Table} from ‘reactstrap’;
import classnames from ‘classnames’;

class Tasks extends Component {


  constructor(props){

    super(props);

    this.state = {

         data: [
        {
          “task_number”:””,
          “work_end”:”10/01/2017”
        },
        {
        etc…
        }
         ]

    }

    this.checkDate = this.checkDate.bind(this);
  }


   checkDate(e) {
    let d = moment.format(“MM/DD/YYYY”);
    let currentData = this.state.data;

    currentData.filter(function(newData){
       if(newData.work_end < d){

         //comes back as undefined
         this.setState({data: newData});
       }
    });
   }

  render(){
    const { data } = this.state;


    let myData = data.map((header, i){
    return (<tr key = {i}>
          <td>{data[i].task_number}</td>
         <td>{data[i].work_end}</td>
                     </tr>)
    });

    return(
        <div>
            <table>
                {myData}
            </table>

        <Input type=“select”
                           name=“assigngroup”
             id=“assigngroup”
            value={this.state.value}
            onChange={this.checkDate}
            />
        </div>
    );
  }


}

export default Tasks;
```

I've also tried creating a new function and passing it from checkDate, but that failed as well.

Comment: you need to bind your functions. Rewrite your `checkDate` and `currentData.filter` to `arrow functions` and hopefully it should work.

Comment: I tried that and it failed as well. It returns with unexpected token and points to the equal sign just have the function name.

 checkDate = (e) => {code in here }

Comment: You need to add this https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-es2015-arrow-functions/

Comment: It's loaded in our webpack js file as a module and the loaders array is correct.

module: {
    rules: [{ 
                 test:/\.(js|jsx)$/,
                 exclude:/node_modules/,
                 use:{
                         loader:'babel-loader',
                         options:{
                                       cacheDirectory:true,
                          }


        }]
}

Comment: @kirdua It doesn't go in the loaders array, it's a plugin.

Comment: I know it's a plugin and it's in our webpack.config.js. We've always had it there and never had to use import into our app.js before.

Comment: Not babel. Im taking about a plugin you need to install to transform arrow functions. You need install the package specified on that page and add the required config to your `babel.rc`.

Comment: What about the `transform-class-properties` plugin?

Comment: Haven't tried it yet. Trying the one on the url that Panther provided earlier. Trying to figure out how to add it to webpack config js file.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript, functions have their own scope so in `checkDate` `this` is your component but, inside the function that you use to filter your `currentData`, `this` is something else.

Your code should go like this:

```
currentData.filter(newData => {
   if(newData.work_end < d){

     this.setState({data: newData});
   }
});
```

or just save `this` in a variable:

```
var self = this;

currentData.filter(function(newData){
   if(newData.work_end < d){

     self.setState({data: newData});
   }
});
```

Comment: I tried that with the same result of undefined for the state.

Comment: @kirdua can you check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jalissa/wu29a52g/1/) it seems to be calling setState just fine saving `this` in a variable.

Comment: it kind of works in my code. Once it gets back down to the let myData map it only renders the last item in the array. When I add a console log I can see all the returned objects in my log.

Comment: That is because the state of data is set for every object that matches `newData.work_end < d` by the time `filter` finishes, `data` is only the last item that matched. If you need to render every matching element you should use @Steve Holgado 's solution with all the conditionals you need and call `setState` with the result of the filter.

Comment: Thanks for the help. It really helped.

Answer (score 1):

The **filter** method returns a new filtered array.

Try this:

```
checkDate(e) {
  let d = moment().format(“MM/DD/YYYY”)
  let currentData = this.state.data
  let filteredData = currentData.filter(item => item.work_end < d)

  this.setState({ data: filteredData })
}
```

Comment: I would but the filter is also going to filter out for the last five days, next five days and what is past due. That's why I have it in a conditional.

Comment: The function passed to **filter** should return **true** or **false** to determine which items are in the returned filtered array. You can use multiple conditions to determine true/false for each item.

Comment: Once I put the conditional in there and put the setState inside the conditional the mydata map returns as not a function.

Comment: Where are you now putting **setState**? If you are using **map** then **this.state.data** will need to be an array.

Comment: I figured it out and keeping the setState in my conditional with the filter. It works well and really appreciate the help.